# Can I use an old SIM from a locked phone in my Redmi?

Tags: sim-card, xiaomi, miui, redmi

I've never had a Smartphone that I used as an actual phone with a SIM before. I have a Redmi 6 I bought overseas (Android 9, MIUI 11) that's only been used with Wi-Fi. I just cut short a long overseas trip due to the COVID crisis. I can't go out to buy a SIM. I can't get one delivered.

I need a phone number to do government stuff online. The online stuff won't work with my sister's phone as a phone number can only be used for one account. My nephew has an old phone with SIM that fits in my phone. The SIM is or was registered to him but has not been used for six to twelve months. The phone was surely locked as is usual for cheap phone packages in Australia. I have no clue whether SIMs are locked to certain phones, or just phones are locked to certain SIMs or certain carriers.

Putting his SIM in my phone, it recognizes the SIM, but not the carrier, phone number, or anything else. I couldn't send a text or receive a text. It does say I can make emergency calls only.

Is it even possible to use a secondhand SIM in my phone? Are my problems due to this not being possible, due to phone settings, or to do with the SIM or the phone service provider (Telstra)?

I can't find anything on the phone about setting up a new SIM. Perhaps some SIMs can only be registered once and are locked to the phone they were packaged with?

Because I'm so totally clueless and my situation has more than a few unique characterists I haven't had any luck Googling a solution yet.

Comment: It really depends on your carrier. Six years ago, I was able to move an AT&T SIM card that had been locked to an iPhone 5 to an unlocked Nexus 4 without issues (in the U.S.). What you might run into, though, is incompatible frequency bands. I'd contact your carrier.

Comment: Yep, reading further into your question, the issue appears to be your new phone not supporting the same frequency bands.

Comment: @gparyani: I could well be wrong but I thought in Australia we only used one band and I checked in Taiwan when I bought the new phone to be sure it would work in Australia too. But I will definitely look into it properly. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: AFAIK, SIM is tied with the carrier and not device (doesn't make sense to tie with device, what if device goes faulty?) so the possibilities are 1. Your phone and SIM are incompatible wrt frequency bands as already suggested 2. SIM is possibly blocked being inactive for a while 3 SIM is faulty

Comment: @beeshyams I checked the freq. bands for both my phone and the sim's phone and they seem compatible. in some parts of my phone it recognizes the carrier, but other places not. maybe some are just user-filled text fields? i think most likely is inactive for not being used for a while. Trying to verify that...

Comment: You can also call the carrier or see on line how to manually enter carrier specific APN settings. Without the correct APN settings, you will not be able to use the phone. Usually, on inserting SIM the carrier sends APN settings to your phone via SMS and you need to simply click to approve - this is with reference to your phone showing carrier info in places

Comment: The APN settings do show up correctly on the phone as compared to what I find via Google.

Comment: ATM that leaves us with faulty or deactivated SIM as possibilities @hippietrail

Comment: @hippietrail Just a dump question: If the SIM has been "not been used for six to twelve months" most likely the contract has ended and hence the SIM card has been deactivated by the carrier. Even prepaid usually get disabled after 6-12 month without loading money onto it. Hence the sim card may be fully functionally (from a physically point of view) but the carrier has just disabled it.